# Arrival probability of Merged Poisson Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

If we have two Poisson process $A$ and $B$ with arrival rate $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$. Now I have question for calculating the probability of an arrival e.g., from process A in the case of merged Poisson process. Which of the approach we should use.

Considering binomial distribution, given an arrival, the probability that this arrival belongs to process A is $\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}}$

Or should we use the traditional Poisson pmf to compute the probability of an arrival from process A, such as using,
$$p_{m}=\frac{(\lambda_{1}t)^{m}.e^{-\lambda_{1}t}}{m!}$$ and we can put m=1 to get the probability of an arrival from process A using only $\lambda_{1}$ in the equation

Comment: Your second approach is unclear. Care to expand on it?

Comment: Since a standard Poisson pmf is $$p_{m}=\frac{(\lambda t)^{m}.e^{-\lambda t}}{m!}$$ where $m$ goes form $0,1,2,3...................$ I used this approach for Process A as Process A has an arrival rate of $\lambda_{1}$ and if I consider a time interval of $t$ for both processes (as observing time interval)..

Comment: Sorry but your explanations do not make much sense to me (and recalling the definition of the Poisson distribution was not exactly *useful* in this perspective, sorry to say).

Comment: No, my question is whether the second way is right or wrong? the objective is to find the probability of an arrival from process A. The first approach is right I know considering the binomial distribution. Since, the Process A is a poisson process ,independent of process B, and for an interval $t$, why can't we use the definition of Poisson process to compute the probability of an arrival from Process A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we have two Poisson process $A$ and $B$ with arrival rate $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$. Now I have question for calculating the probability of an arrival e.g., from process A in the case of merged Poisson process. Which of the approach we should use.

If you have two *independent* Poisson processes, then the probabiliy that any particular arrival in the merged process was generated by process $A$ is indeed $\lambda_1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$ .

A Poisson process consists of point events (arrivals) that occur over an interval at a constant average rate but each *independently* of any other arrival in the process.

Thus in the merged process you have arrivals that occur at a constant joint rate $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$ and each *independently* generated by one from the two *independent* Possion processes.

---

Your aproach seems to be asking the condtional probability that, in a *very small* interval, we get one arrival from process A and no arrival from process B, given that we get only one arrival from the merged process in that *very small* interval.   Well...sure.

$$\lim\limits_{\Delta t\to 0^+}\cfrac{~\cfrac{(\lambda_1\Delta t)^1e^{-\lambda_1\Delta t}}{1!}\cdot\cfrac{(\lambda_2\Delta t)^0e^{-\lambda_2\Delta t}~}{0!}}{\cfrac{((\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\Delta t)^1e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\Delta t}}{1!}}~=~\dfrac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$$

---

[Of course, to use this approach you have to first establish that the count of arrivals in the joint process follows a Poisson distribution with the combined average rate.]

Comment: Many thanks @Graham Kemp. got it.